# Add DataBinding for attached Property per Code Behind

Tags: c#, data-binding, code-behind, attached-properties

I want to add a DataBinding per Codebehind for an attached Property and want to show the `Canvas.Left` property in a TextBox. How do I add this property?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear from your question, but I think you're asking how one would bind to the attached property `Canvas.Left` and show it in a TextBox. I'll assume you want it for a control other than the TextBox.

```xaml
<Canvas>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=(Canvas.Left)}" />
   <Button x:Name="button" Content="Press me" />
</Canvas>
```

Note the brackets around the attached property.

EDIT:
To do the equivalent in code, use the following:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = button;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty);
textBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Code binding does not work as in sample code.
Third line should read like 
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.Left);

Comment: Thank ageektrapped. 

But i search a way per codebehind, exactly per C#. I know the way per WPF.