# Bind in code to Bindable Attached Property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, attached-properties

From official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties):

> The namespace declaration is then used when setting the attached property on a specific control, as demonstrated in the following XAML code example:

```
<Label Text="Label Shadow Effect" local:ShadowEffect.HasShadow="true" />
```

> The equivalent C# code is shown in the following code example:

```
var label = new Label { Text = "Label Shadow Effect" }; ShadowEffect.SetHasShadow (label, true);
```

**My question:**

Which would be the equivalent C# code for the following XAML binding:

```
<Label Text="Label Shadow Effect" local:ShadowEffect.HasShadow="{Binding HasShadow}" />
```

**Example scenario**

I have a `LongPressEffect` that exposes an attached Bindable Property `Command`. The effect is attached to a `Label` as shown below:

```
<Label x:Name="LongPressLabel"
       Text="Long press me"
       effects:LongPressEffect.Command = "{Binding MyCommand}">
   <Label.Effects>
       <effects:LongPressEffect />
   </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

How do I do the same binding on C# code?

**Similar threads**

Seems to be the same problem presented [here](https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/79932/attached-property-binding-in-code). Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add DataBinding for attached Property per Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600441/add-databinding-for-attached-property-per-code-behind)

Comment: Not really. What that thread mentions is to bind the property `Text` which belongs to the TextBox to an attached property (being the attached property in the `path` of the binding). What I want is to bind the attached property (a property that doesn't belong to the Element by itself, in my XAML example the `Label`) to another property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this works for me:

```cs
var label = new Label()
{
    Text = "Long press me"
};

var longPressedEffect = new LongPressedEffect();
label.Effects.Add(longPressedEffect);

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = nameof(MyCommand);
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
label.SetBinding(longPressedEffect.CommandProperty, binding);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties#consuming-the-effect), you can try the following code:

```
        label1.Effects.Add(new LongPressedEffect());
        LongPressedEffect.SetCommand(label1,mycommand);
```

The equivalent Label in C#

```
   <Label
        x:Name="label1"
        effects:LongPressedEffect.Command="{Binding command1}"
        effects:LongPressedEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        Text="Long Press Me!">
        <Label.Effects>
            <effects:LongPressedEffect />
        </Label.Effects>
    </Label>
```

Comment: As I see it, using `LongPressedEffect.SetCommand(label1,mycommand)` just sets a static value to the LongPressedEffect Command and not a binding, which would change the value when mycommand changes